# Copy Google Analytics View does not copy "content grouping" rules

Tags: google-analytics

When you copy a view in google analytics "content grouping" is not copied to the new view.

If copying the view does not work then how can i copy or move "content grouping rules" between views ?

I have a lot of rules and i can't recreate everything each time i tried a new view.

Comment: I don't think you can. I had a look at the GA Management API reference, and apparently you cannot set up content groupings via the API. So the only way I see would be some clever browser automation script that reads and saves the DOM in the original view and then inserts it in the copied view when you navigate there, but that sounds like more work than doing it by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like a major limitation if you have more than 50 rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eike Says, yes the account creation seems to be limited as the API, i run some test and the Channel Grouping, Content Grouping and Calculated Metrics are not being passed to the new account.

So them, what is copie? : You can find the list of parameters copied with this feature.

```
{
  "id": string,
  "kind": "analytics#profile",   //unmutable
  "selfLink": string,
  "accountId": string,
  "webPropertyId": string,
  "internalWebPropertyId": string,
  "name": string,
  "currency": string,
  "timezone": string,
  "websiteUrl": string,
  "defaultPage": string,
  "excludeQueryParameters": string,
  "siteSearchQueryParameters": string,
  "stripSiteSearchQueryParameters": boolean,
  "siteSearchCategoryParameters": string,
  "stripSiteSearchCategoryParameters": boolean,
  "type": string,
  "permissions": {
    "effective": [
      string
    ]
  },
  "created": datetime,
  "updated": datetime,
  "eCommerceTracking": boolean,
  "enhancedECommerceTracking": boolean,
  "botFilteringEnabled": boolean,
  "starred": boolean,
  "parentLink": {
    "type": "analytics#webproperty",
    "href": string
  },
  "childLink": {
    "type": "analytics#goals",
    "href": string
  }
}
```

What I do to override this limitation is build a Javascript+Jquery function that clicks on the differents element to automatice the Channel Grouping (this because i got a tons of rules too)

Greetings